How to Manage Multiple ApplicationIDs for different Environments in GeneXus 18U8 with GAM for a WEB/.NET Core Application?
I have a GeneXus 18 Upgrade 8 Knowledge Base with GAM that generates a WEB/.NET Core application.
I have only one version and two environments, and I need to generate two different ApplicationIDs, one for each environment. Currently, the property is set at the version level, and the documentation states that only one ApplicationID can be used for WEB applications (but supports multiple ApplicationIDs for mobile applications).
Can it cause any problems to change the application.gam file at deployment time for a web application?
In GAM, is it possible to set the ApplicationID using environment variables?

I'll answer my own question.
Different Web Applications for Different Environments: If you need to manage different Application IDs for different environments, you will need to deploy a separate web application for each environment. This involves creating distinct deployments for each environment, each with its own application.gam file containing the respective Application ID.
You cannot use the application.gam file generated by GeneXus; instead, you must create a new one manually.
To the question:
In GAM, is it possible to set the ApplicationID using environment variables?
NO, it is not possible to use environment variables to set the ApplicationID in GAM in Genexus 18 Upgrade 8.
